# Get all database table results using an array of ids

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my foreach loop, I get a separate array every time. I want to combine all these results into one array. I have tried `array_merge()` but it is not working. Is there another way?

The results are two dimensional arrays.

```
foreach ($location as $loc) 
{
    $query = "SELECT name FROM locations WHERE location_id = $loc";
    $query = $this->db->query($query);
    $data = $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: This is very bad approach. Don't run SQL in loops. Alternatively, create your query in loop to run it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use  `array_merge()`:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($location as $loc) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM locations l WHERE l.location_id = " . $loc;
    $query = $this->db->query($query);
    $data  = array_merge($data, $query->result_array());
}
```

...or merge the location id's first and then do a **single** query, which is much faster:

```
$in    = implode(', ', $location);
$query = "SELECT name FROM locations l WHERE l.location_id IN (" . $in . ")";
$query = $this->db->query($query);
$data  = $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$q = 'SELECT `name` FROM `locations` AS `l` WHERE ';
foreach ($location as $loc) {
    $q .= "`l`.`location_id` = '$loc' OR ";
}
$q = rtrim($q, 'OR ');
$query = $this->db->query($q);
$data = $query->result_array();
```